HTML cant render on FLASK because of quirks mode(maybe)
well, i was learning FLASK, but when at part of html templates, i cant figure out why my html can't rendering, i use the crome f12 and found that it shown quirks mode and i already set  to my html file, so i dont know how to disable it, and i dont know if quirks mode was the main issue.
i alredy set the directory of my html file inside the "templates" directory
here are my flask:
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<name>')
def user(name):
    return f"hellp {name}"


@app.route('/admin')
def admin():
    return redirect(url_for('user', name="admin123"))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


and my html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>hello fu yah</p>
</body>
</html>

and my directory looks like this:
my file directory on vscode
first i try running as my tutorial goes, but my html wont rendering and i found in chrome console that it was in quirks mode
i try before the return on the flask code i add print statement, in case of like that function didn't run, but it does show in my console but still the html wasn't rendering
